# Secure account registration from iPhone to API

Tags: ios, rest, security, encryption, rsa

First time app developer here, so sorry if this seems silly.
I am building a login/registration screen for iOS. My plan is to send the username/password to a REST API endpoint which will then check if they exist in the DB.
My question is, how do I encrypt either the channel between phone and endpoint OR encrypt the information being sent in order to prevent a man-in-the-middle attack. And how would I be able to decrypt it at the endpoint without sending the key?

Thanks!

Comment: You should use HTTPS and certificate pinning.

Comment: Don't save the password on the server, instead save a hash. he hash really needs to be seeded, PBKDF2 is a good solution. Save the seed along with the password. Also a must is using two-factor authentication on the server.

Comment: @zaph oh yes, I will be saving the hash. I should've mentioned.

Comment: so I just need to make the REST API use http secure...that's it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use https with certificate pinning, that will give you a secure encrypted channel between the app and server, even any query string is encrypted.

Don't save the password on the server, instead save a hash. The hash really needs to be seeded, PBKDF2 is a good solution. Save the randomly generated seed along with the password.

When the server receives the user and password looks up the the user and gets the salt and hashed password. Hashes the received with the salt and compares the two hashes. The server never saves the password.

Refer to reputable sources for the exact details, obviously this is glossing over details. If there is real value being protected hire a cryptographic domain expert.

Also a must is using two-factor authentication on the server.